# Interpolate pixel rectangle that are out of image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, interpolation, subpixel, bilinear-interpolation

I am recently reading the code of [`cv::getRectSubPix`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga77576d06075c1a4b6ba1a608850cd614) in OpenCV, which involves dealing rectangles out of image. Concretely, I am stuck on function [`adjustRect`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/808ba552c532408bddd5fe51784cf4209296448a/modules/imgproc/src/samplers.cpp#L52-L102) that is used to reshape the out-of-bounds rectangular window.
According to the code of `adjustRect`, top left corner `p=(x,y)` of rectangle will shift to `p'=(-x,-y)`(blue frame) if `p`(red frame) is as follows:
[image]
What puzzled me was the last line in `adjustRect`:

```
return src - rect.x*pix_size;
```

why `src` is shifted in `x` direction only? To my understanding, proper code should be:

```
return src - rect.x*pix_size-rect.y*src_step
```

Besides, I think `src` will point to undefined memory if both `x` and `y` are negative. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `adjustRect` should be considered together with codes in [`getRectSubPix_Cn_`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/808ba552c532408bddd5fe51784cf4209296448a/modules/imgproc/src/samplers.cpp#L184-L214). OpenCV adopts different interpolation strategies when pixel rectangle is out of image.
It will dereference properly when indexing pixels because:

```
s0 = src[r.x*cn + c]*b1 + src2[r.x*cn + c]*b2; .
```

For my case, this interpolation scheme is depicted in following figure:
[image]
 This post waits to be updated because I think there should be more details to be discovered.